# How to find the Linear Equation given 3 vectors?

Tags: vectors

Let $a = <2,3,1>,\  b = <1,2,3>$ and $c = <4, 19, k>$.

Find the value of $k$ such that the vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$ all lie on the same plane.

I have already solved for the normal by the cross product of $A$ and $B$ which is $\left(7,-5,1\right)$

How do I find a point of between the vectors to finish my linear equation: $ax + by + cz = a_0x + b_0yo =c_0z$

Comment: Please use MathJax to type your questions and explain what equalities you’re using to say that the 3 vectors belong to the same plane.

Comment: solve $(7,-5,1)\cdot(4,19,k)=(7,-5,1)\cdot(2,3,1)$

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is the plane determined y $a$ and $b$ then it would be orthogonal to the normal. So the inner product between $c$ and $(7,-5,2)$ must be $0$ and this gives $k=67$.